# ArrayList in ArrayList<String>

Tags: android

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> childlist = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3 i++){
   String chlidtext = chlidlist + String.valueof(i);
   String maintext = mainlist +String.Valueof(i);
   childlist.add(chlidtext);
   mainlist.add(maintext);
}
```

> ```
>  return mainlist;
> ```

i dont have an idea how to get 3rd element in every chlidlist ?

Comment: mainlist.add(maintext) --> you are adding String in place of arrayList.

Comment: You are having only 3 child nodes? 
(start the i value from 2 and then increment it by 3 )

Comment: Are you sure that this line mainlist.add(maintext); is OK? I would say mainlist.add(childlist).

Comment: its not working if i use for/for each loop it display one 1st mainlist 3rd childlist item 3x times

Comment: You may get exception because you should add ArrayList<String> to mainlist, but you are adding String here. And you can get 3rd element of an arraylist by giving its index to get method. mainlist.get(2) will return 3rd element.

Comment: yes besworland your are correct mainlist.add(childlist). sorry typing mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access 3rd element of childList by:

```
mainList.get(index).get(2); // Here 1st get() will get the 1st element of mainList which conatins 1st child element and 2nd get() will get the 3rd element of childlist.
```

Comment: i tried 
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
  mainlist.get(i).get(2);
}
it will display mainlist 1 chlidlist 3rd item. 3x times